# c# SqlDataReader

Tags: c#

This logic get data from a database and checks if the inbound `ipAddress` is within the range or if its equal to one we have stored in the system. In production its using a `SqlDataReader` but in the working sample I am just using a `DataTable`. How I could possibly improve the code quality with using the `SqlDataReader`

```
public static bool CheckIPAddressRange(string accessKey, string ipAddress)
{
   bool canAccess = false;
   string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
   SQLHelper sql = new SQLHelper(conn);
   SqlParameter[] parms = new SqlParameter[] {
      new SqlParameter("@AccessKey", SqlDbType.VarChar,36),
   };

   parms[0].Value = accessKey;

   SqlDataReader dr = sql.ExecuteReaderStoreProcedure("dbo.[Select_IPRange]", parms);
   while (dr.Read())
   {
       bool IsRange = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["IsRange"]);
       if (IsRange == true){
       canAccess = IsInRange(Convert.ToString(dr["IPAddress"]), Convert.ToString(dr["IPEndAddress"]), ipAddress);
        }
        else
        {
        string accessIP = Convert.ToString(dr["IPAddress"]);
            if (ipAddress == accessIP){
                canAccess = true;
             }
       }
       if (canAccess == true){
           break;
       }
}
            dr.Close();
            return canAccess;
}
```

working sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/1nE9h3

Comment: From what aspect are you expecting a review?

Comment: like is it a bad practice to have the three if statements? and I do alot of Convert.ToString and ToBoolean is that  bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my suggestions

#### SqlParameter

You can use the object initializer to set the `Value` directly like this

```
var spParameters = new SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@AccessKey", SqlDbType.VarChar, 36) { Value = accessKey }
};
```

#### `Convert.ToString` vs `GetString`

- You can convert your `dr` to a `IDataReader` interface

  - You can use there `GetBoolean`, `GetString`, etc.
  - They require an index so you have to use `GetOrdinal` to translate column name to index
- Your branching logic could be simplified like this

```
bool ProcessRecord(IDataRecord record, string ipAddress)
{
    bool isRange = record.GetBoolean(record.GetOrdinal("IsRange"));
    if (isRange)
    {
        return IsInRange(record.GetString(record.GetOrdinal("IPAddress")),
                        record.GetString(record.GetOrdinal("IPEndAddress")),
                        ipAddress);
    }
    else
    {
        return ipAddress == record.GetString(record.GetOrdinal("IPAddress"));
    }
}
```

#### DataReader

With the above helper method your main `while` loop can be simplified like this

```
SqlDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReaderStoreProcedure("dbo.[Select_IPRange]", spParameters);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (canAccess = ProcessRecord((IDataRecord)reader, ipAddress))
        break;
}
reader.Close();
return canAccess;
```

Comment: do I need to check if `record.GetBoolean(record.GetOrdinal("IsRange"))` is null?

Comment: @Jefferson If the `IsRange` is nullable then yes you should check. Naive impl: `!record.IsDBNull(record.GetOrdinal("IsRange")) ? record.GetBoolean(record.GetOrdinal("IsRange")) : false`

Comment: @Jefferson To reduce repetitive code: `var columnIdx = record.GetOrdinal("IsRange");` and then `!record.IsDBNull(columnIdx) ? record.GetBoolean(columnIdx) : false`